# Difference com.sun.jersey and org.glassfish.jersey

Tags: java, glassfish, jersey, sun

What is the difference between `com.sun.jersey` and `org.glassfish.jersey`?

Currently I have my REST service working on `com.sun.jersey` and I want to write tests, but I can't find a good tutorial for this (nothing seems to work). However, I can find good documentation about the `org.glassfish.jersey` tests.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

The only difference between com.sun.jersey and org.glassfish.jersey is that the package name was changed because Jersey team is now part of another organization (Glassfish).
Versions below 2 use package com.sun.jersey, versions above 2 use org.glassfish.jersey.
And yes, there are some differences between 1.x and 2.x.

Comment: Tip: This version divide can also be seen a Maven Central Repository: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cjersey-server

Comment: Jersey 2.0 provides support for Java SE HTTP Server, Grizzly 2 HTTP server, Servlet 2.5 or higher containers as well as OSGi containers on the server side and HTTPURLConnection-based or Grizzly asynchronous client transport connectors. To leverage JAX-RS/Jersey server-side async features in a Servlet container, you need a container that supports Servlet 3.0 at least. Jersey supports asynchronous resource invocations on Grizzly 2 HTTP server too. (Ref - http://marek.potociar.net/2013/06/13/jax-rs-2-0-and-jersey-2-0-released/)

Comment: For me the big difference is that com.sun.jersey works and org.glassfish.jersey doesn't. lol